# Monitor problem

Tags: monitor

After installing Xubuntu, I was trying to adjust the resolution of my Compaq all in one computer. I made the mistake of clicking on the second monitor, wich is not existent. Now all I can see is the background picture of the second monitor. How do I get back to see what is on the main monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Try in console `xrandr --auto` this should fix it.